# Target the First Visible Element After the First Active Element in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Getting into some pretty gnarly CSS here. In the below scenario, I want to only match #4. This is what I have going on:

```
<ul class="tabMenu">
  <li class="hidden">1</li>
  <li class="active">2</li>
  <li class="hidden">3</li>
  <li>4</li> <!-- I want this one's blood -->
  <li class="hidden">5</li>
  <li class="hidden">6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li class="hidden">8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Here are my attempts, which are failing:

```
/* Only matches the next immediate li (so it works if #3 is not hidden) */
.tabMenu li:not(.hidden).active + li:not(.hidden) a {
  color: red;
}

/* Matches #4 and #7, I just want #4 */
.tabMenu li:not(.hidden).active ~ li:not(.hidden) a {
  color: red;
}
```

After 30 minutes on this I have decided to bring my problem to you. Please help!

Comment: is the li you want to reach has really no class ?

Comment: You could put .visible on #4 and #7 if you wanted

Comment: what if `li` 3 had an `active` class on it, would you want 3's blood or 4's?

Comment: @Relfor  if 3 was active I'd want 4 still

Comment: alrighty updated my targetting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking advantage of the way CSS sibling selectors work will be the way to go here.

- *Step 1:* Let us perform a selection of all the elements after the first `active` one which does not contain the class `hidden` or `active`.

  ```
  li.active ~ li:not(.hidden):not(.active) {
      color:red;
  }
  ```
- *Step 2:* Let us remove the target of all the siblings *after* the targeted elements. The CSS selector `~` selects all sibling elements which come after it, and NOT including it. Thus by applying it to the `li` elements after the target, we successfully remove from all the elements *except* the first one which was targeted in step 1.

  ```
  li.active ~ li:not(.hidden):not(.active) ~ li {
      color:inherit;
  }
  ```

See this happening at: http://jsfiddle.net/nJHd2/